# How do I rescue a skirt that I attempted to lengthen but now has a very wavy hem?

Tags: sewing, clothing, technique-selection

I tried to upcycle a skirt by adding a lace trim to increase the length, but I think it sticks out like a sore thumb.
The skirt is straight but the hem below has extreme waves.

How can I flatten these waves?

Or can I add horsehair braid to the back of the skirt (above the pink frills) so that the waviness is consistent between the skirt and the trim?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the materials and cut of the skirt, it behaves exactly like I would expect it to. Since the circumference of the bottom hem is bigger than the hip circumference, the skirt has to either stand out in a cone shape or fold in in places until the outer silhouette resembles a barrel. This property is called **the drape of fabric**.

A great example can be seen in Melly Sews' article [One pattern, many fabrics. Understanding fabric drape](https://mellysews.com/what-is-fabric-drape/)

[image]

The material of the skirt looks somewhat stiff (possibly linen?), so it has no drape and naturally stands out in a cone shape. Adding any more weight to the bottom is more likely to draw it into a wavy barrel shape. Adding more stiffness (like calico, horsehair braid or interfacing) to the hem can increase the stiffness and revert it to its cone shape (but only for fabrics that have little drape to begin with).

---

Speaking about fashion, style and aesthetics is obviously always a subjective topic, but this skirt clearly is meant to have a cone shape. In a typical circle skirt the bottom hem is *much* wider than the hip, so it's *supposed* to fall down in waves. But here to bottom circumference is only very slightly bigger than the hip, so there can only be very few, very big waves, which looks odd. So my personal recommendation is to keep the bottom hem as wide and circular as possible.

The color of the trim is another problem. Yes, it sticks out like a sore thumb, because it's the only bright color on the entire skirt. If you want to use this trim, I suggest adding a strip of either the same trim or a ribbon of the same color above the trim and optionally at the hip. Something like this:

[image]

It gives the entire skirt a rounded appearance and makes the trim look *intentional*

The trim itself can be considered another problem, depending on your taste. The upper edge is pleated, making the upper circumference smaller than the lower one. Just like the skirt, this trim will stand out in a cone shape. If you like this shape, keep it, it looks cute. If you don't like it, you have to either use a different trim or unpick the pleats from this trim.

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation. Yes, the skirt is linen. I had planned to add pink appliqué flowers but I like your idea of adding border above the hem and at the waist. Please clarify, will adding horsehair braid help, and how?

Comment: @Marium To be completely honest, I never used horsehair braid and don't know how flexible it is. It is very lightweight, so that's a bonus. But it seems to be braided on the bias (at a 45° angle instead of a 90° angle), which makes it possible to pull and push... If you already have horsehair braid, try pinning it to half of the skirt with straight pins and look how much it improves the outline. Another solution is to remove weight from the hem. The lace looks like it might be doubled, so removing one layer should improve the shape. Adding more flowers will surely make it worse.

Comment: I don’t have horsehair braid but I may get it. I really want to save this skirt!

Comment: @Marium I looked around the internet a bit and it looks like horsehair ribbon could easily do the job. However, as with most things concerning sewing, there are different grades of stiffness and quality. If you have the chance, go to a sewing supply shop in your area and feel the ribbon they have on offer, then buy the stiffest. If that's not an option for you, please buy from a reputable online shop and don't chose the cheapest one (they are usually the flimsiest). Pro tip: sewing the ribbon on with 3 lines of stitching (top, bottom, center) should make it a tiny bit stiffer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance!

Answer (score 2):

My apologies to interrupt you, ladies, I hope that you don't mind us (gents) comment on your clothings.  But, I have to admit, we care about your looks more than ours, and I think I have to say that you better do it this way:

### Synopsis

[image]

### Key Design Elements

Here are the key design elements that I suggest:

- Add spirals by means of stitches, and some straight cloth (that is not fluffy). Straight cloths seem more relaxing, while fluffs feel rough.
- Also, whatever straight fabric that you use to create those spiraling lines, make sure that they're a variation of some white, very similar to the colour of the skirt itself.  Try to avoid any strong colour variations.  Because, similar colours are, again, more relaxing to the observer, while stark colour changes (such as a sudden pink) implies a conflict (subconsciously at least).
- Make sure the spirals are in the same direction, but also make sure that their angles and turning speed are different, so that they feel *natural*, like a flower, or an organic thing (not a machined thing).  When something looks a bit varying, in a natural way, it gives a more relaxing feeling to the observer that he/she is an integral part of nature (not a robot).
- Extend the skirt, however you want it, by adding new spiral layers.  It can grow as long as you want to be.  It can even grow so long, you drag it behind you.
- When you end the skirt, do not make it flat (horizontal to the ground), instead make it end in an angle, so one side is higher, in a way to reflect the spirals.
- Delete that pink fluffiness.

### Extra Thoughts

In case it is too hot, you may leave the spiral lines open from behind in some areas to allow air to freely circulate, while (at the same time) offer privacy by not allowing people to see what's behind.

For example, the straight fabric that you add to overlay on the spirals may have gaps behind it for airflow.

This way, you will feel cooler and have the effect of wearing lighter skirts, while looking like a long one.

I'm not sure if you want this extra air-circulation idea, but I think it's a neat trick, and generally helps with skirts (because skirts are nice for cooling; for heating, pants are better as they trap air).

### Final Remarks

I think, if done right with care, without rushing, but with adequate planning, drawings, mockups using pins, etc, it will eventually look better than the original one.

However, I'm not sure how much of your time it will consume, and whether it is worth your time.  Henceforth, if I were you, I'd do this:

- If I'm feeling experimenting and risk-taking, I'd do it, while putting in my mind that the risk might be that errors may ruin the skirt.
- Else, I'd drop this plan.

Side note: I commend you for trying to re-use old things.  I think such behaviour is a sign of a higher intelligence.  All the best.

Comment: I don't think you have to point out your gender at all (nor the reasoning behind it), although it does paint a funny picture coming from a user named 'caveman' :)

Comment: It helps to indicate that this whole thing is an opinion and not a fact.  If that part is deleted, then the rest of answer seems too confident, or too certain about its claims.  I do not want to leave the impression that the answer is a 'fact'.  I want it express the silliness/subjectivity in it, so that the reader knows how extremely subjective this whole thing is.

Comment: Thank you. I got rid of pink fluff and replaced it with cream color lace trim :-)